# Telling if a Redstone Energy Cell is full -Recent Tekkit-

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-tekkit

Is there any way to tell if a Redstone Energy Cell is full in the Galacticraft version of Tekkit? Any form of emitting a redstone signal when it is full to turn off my engines would be great.

Comment: if there is buildcraft then use a gate

Comment: @ratchetfreak Tekkit and feed-the-beast are different packs and work differently.

Comment: @3ventic but both contain the same mods with the only crucial ones here being Thermal expansion and buildcraft

Comment: @ratchetfreak but they're implemented in a different way. I have many times checked [a-mod-in-tekkit] wiki for something only to find out it doesn't work that way in tekkit. At least tekkit not only ties the mods together, but it also modifies them to interact better with each other. For this reason I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: This question *is* a duplicate, kinda. The other question is for a different mod pack but the solution does work on my version of Tekkit. So, I believe this question should at least exist to help people find a solution faster but it shouldn't be reopened for answers.

Comment: Kinda Happy My answer was used again. :)